# IBOutlets and IBActions Not Showing up in View Controller in the main.storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the new xcode 5. I typed in all my IBOutlets and IBActions in the View.controller.h and I declared all of them there. But when I go to link up my actions and outlets to my labels and buttons in the main.storyboard, none of my IBoutlets and IBActions i declared are showing up. And Note : I did make sure the view controller in outlined in blue (meaning i am in the view controller ) . Thank YOU!

Answer (score 2):

your view controller class name instead of Default class name

[image]

Then draw your widget control to your class view controller

[image]